# Reading .raw file containing Heightmap

Tags: c++, directx-11, heightmap

I am using the libnoise library to generate a random terrain and saving it in a .raw file that has its elevation points measured in meters.  This terrain file contains 16-bit signed big-endian values, in row-major order, ordered south to north. This is the code I am using for reading the file.

```
struct HeightMapType
    {
        float x, y, z;
        float nx, ny, nz;
        float r, g, b;
    };

bool Terrain::LoadRawFile()
{
    int error, i, j, index;
    FILE* filePtr;
    unsigned long long imageSize, count;
    unsigned short* rawImage;


    // Create the float array to hold the height map data.
    m_heightMap = new HeightMapType[m_terrainWidth * m_terrainHeight];
    if(!m_heightMap)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Open the 16 bit raw height map file for reading in binary.
    error = fopen_s(&filePtr, m_terrainFilename, "rb");
    if(error != 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Calculate the size of the raw image data.
    imageSize = m_terrainHeight * m_terrainWidth;

    // Allocate memory for the raw image data.
    rawImage = new unsigned short[imageSize];
    if(!rawImage)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Read in the raw image data.
    count = fread(rawImage, sizeof(unsigned short), imageSize, filePtr);
    if(count != imageSize)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Close the file.
    error = fclose(filePtr);
    if(error != 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Copy the image data into the height map array.
    for(j=0; j<m_terrainHeight; j++)
    {
        for(i=0; i<m_terrainWidth; i++)
        {
            index = (m_terrainWidth * j) + i;

            // Store the height at this point in the height map array.
            m_heightMap[index].y = (float)rawImage[index];
        }
    }

    // Release the bitmap image data.
    delete [] rawImage;
    rawImage = 0;

    // Release the terrain filename now that it has been read in.
    delete [] m_terrainFilename;
    m_terrainFilename = 0;

    return true;
}
```

The code does not return any error but this is the result rendered: [rawFileRendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRC86.jpg).

I tested the code with another heightmap saved in a raw file (given by rastertek) and it works.

Do you know why the rendered scene is like this? 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You use `unsigned short`, but you said in the description that the numbers are signed. So you should use `signed short` instead
2. You don't do anything with endianness. If you are on a little endian machine, you should convert your values from big endian to little endian.

You can convert endianness with this:

```
short endianConvert(short x) {
    unsigned short v = (unsigned short)x;
    return (short)(v>>8|v<<8);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it still does not change the rendered image. Is there a way to find the differences between the two different raw file in order to understand what''s wrong?

Comment: There must be some change. If it is not changed at all, then there is some other problem in your code. If you share the .raw file, I could look into it, what's in there.

Comment: Ok thank you! you can find the link here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5qZUPGKjCpqUW1iMlVIV3Z0M0E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I can render pretty well terrain.raw. The problems are with the terrainLIB.raw file

Comment: @Swagging: it seems that these two files have a different format. Even, terrain.raw doesn't contain what you described. As I see, it contains a 2049x2049 map, where each point stored in a byte (not 16-bit signed int). terrainLIB.raw seems to be more complicated, maybe it has the format you described. If I look at this file the way you described, I see a highly noisy map.

Comment: terrainLIB.raw  should be a heightmap where each pixel represents a height in meters. Do you know if there's a way to implement a reader for that kind of raw file, in a way that the rendered terrain will not be like the picture above?

Comment: @Swagging: I've update my answer with two pictures. Do you think that terrainLIB is right?

Comment: It does not seem right to me at all, but I got it from the examples of the liboise library and in the description of the raw file it was written ".raw file that has its elevation points measured in meters. This terrain file contains 16-bit signed big-endian values, in row-major order, ordered south to north. This is the code I am using for reading the file.". That's why I'm not sure.

Comment: @Swagging: is this libnoise freely available? If yes, where? Can I find this terrainLIB.raw file in libnoise? I'm now curious what the heck this file contain :)

Comment: Sure! the library can be found here : http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/index.html              Go to downloads for downloading it and you need to run the 'Complex planetary surface'  example and run it. Inside that there is everything you need ;)

Comment: If you run that example you should find in your folder a terrain.raw file. That is my terrainLIB.raw

Comment: @Swagging: have you modified its sourcecode? Because here, it generated a 16MB file, and it seems to be perfectly fine. So, it means that your terrainLIB.raw surely wrong.

Comment: I guess I messed up then, I tried again and it worked, I'll probably changed some values. I am sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: @Swagging: no problem :) I think I'll delete my comments here tomorrow, as they don't add anything to the answer now.